# delayed job failing to send email in rails app.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, actionmailer, mandrill

I'm setting up a prelaunch site using https://github.com/harrystech/prelaunchr and I'm having trouble getting the mailer working.

here's the error I'm getting:

```
Class#signup_email failed with ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `encoding' for {:host=>"localhost:3000"}:Hash - 0 failed attempts
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.7ms)  UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET "last_error" = 'undefined method `encoding'' for {:host=>"localhost:3000"}:Hash
```

I've tried to configure my development environment to use Mandril app for sending emails.

Here's what I have so far.

```
Mail.rb
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.mandrill.app.com",
    port: 587,
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: "MYEMAIL,
    password: "Mandrilapi key",
    authentication: "login"
}

ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.default charset: "utf8"
```

devise.rb

```
# Use this hook to configure devise mailer, warden hooks and so forth.
# Many of these configuration options can be set straight in your model.
Devise.setup do |config|
  # ==> Mailer Configuration
  # Configure the e-mail address which will be shown in Devise::Mailer,
  # note that it will be overwritten if you use your own mailer class with default "from" parameter.
  config.mailer_sender = "myemail"

  # Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
  # config.mailer = "Devise::Mailer"

  # ==> ORM configuration
  # Load and configure the ORM. Supports :active_record (default) and
  # :mongoid (bson_ext recommended) by default. Other ORMs may be
  # available as additional gems.
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'

  # ==> Configuration for any authentication mechanism
  # Configure which keys are used when authenticating a user. The default is
  # just :email. You can configure it to use [:username, :subdomain], so for
  # authenticating a user, both parameters are required. Remember that those
  # parameters are used only when authenticating and not when retrieving from
  # session. If you need permissions, you should implement that in a before filter.
  # You can also supply a hash where the value is a boolean determining whether
  # or not authentication should be aborted when the value is not present.
  # config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]

  # Configure parameters from the request object used for authentication. Each entry
  # given should be a request method and it will automatically be passed to the
  # find_for_authentication method and considered in your model lookup. For instance,
  # if you set :request_keys to [:subdomain], :subdomain will be used on authentication.
  # The same considerations mentioned for authentication_keys also apply to request_keys.
  # config.request_keys = []

  # Configure which authentication keys should be case-insensitive.
  # These keys will be downcased upon creating or modifying a user and when used
  # to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]

  # Configure which authentication keys should have whitespace stripped.
  # These keys will have whitespace before and after removed upon creating or
  # modifying a user and when used to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]

  # Tell if authentication through request.params is enabled. True by default.
  # It can be set to an array that will enable params authentication only for the
  # given strategies, for example, `config.params_authenticatable = [:database]` will
  # enable it only for database (email + password) authentication.
  # config.params_authenticatable = true

  # Tell if authentication through HTTP Basic Auth is enabled. False by default.
  # It can be set to an array that will enable http authentication only for the
  # given strategies, for example, `config.http_authenticatable = [:token]` will
  # enable it only for token authentication.
  # config.http_authenticatable = false

  # If http headers should be returned for AJAX requests. True by default.
  # config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = true

  # The realm used in Http Basic Authentication. "Application" by default.
  # config.http_authentication_realm = "Application"

  # It will change confirmation, password recovery and other workflows
  # to behave the same regardless if the e-mail provided was right or wrong.
  # Does not affect registerable.
  # config.paranoid = true

  # By default Devise will store the user in session. You can skip storage for
  # :http_auth and :token_auth by adding those symbols to the array below.
  # Notice that if you are skipping storage for all authentication paths, you
  # may want to disable generating routes to Devise's sessions controller by
  # passing :skip => :sessions to `devise_for` in your config/routes.rb
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]

  # ==> Configuration for :database_authenticatable
  # For bcrypt, this is the cost for hashing the password and defaults to 10. If
  # using other encryptors, it sets how many times you want the password re-encrypted.
  #
  # Limiting the stretches to just one in testing will increase the performance of
  # your test suite dramatically. However, it is STRONGLY RECOMMENDED to not use
  # a value less than 10 in other environments.
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10

  # Setup a pepper to generate the encrypted password.
  # config.pepper = "secret"

  # ==> Configuration for :confirmable
  # A period that the user is allowed to access the website even without
  # confirming his account. For instance, if set to 2.days, the user will be
  # able to access the website for two days without confirming his account,
  # access will be blocked just in the third day. Default is 0.days, meaning
  # the user cannot access the website without confirming his account.
  # config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 2.days

  # A period that the user is allowed to confirm their account before their
  # token becomes invalid. For example, if set to 3.days, the user can confirm
  # their account within 3 days after the mail was sent, but on the fourth day
  # their account can't be confirmed with the token any more.
  # Default is nil, meaning there is no restriction on how long a user can take
  # before confirming their account.
  # config.confirm_within = 3.days

  # If true, requires any email changes to be confirmed (exactly the same way as
  # initial account confirmation) to be applied. Requires additional unconfirmed_email
  # db field (see migrations). Until confirmed new email is stored in
  # unconfirmed email column, and copied to email column on successful confirmation.
  config.reconfirmable = true

  # Defines which key will be used when confirming an account
  # config.confirmation_keys = [ :email ]

  # ==> Configuration for :rememberable
  # The time the user will be remembered without asking for credentials again.
  # config.remember_for = 2.weeks

  # If true, extends the user's remember period when remembered via cookie.
  # config.extend_remember_period = false

  # Options to be passed to the created cookie. For instance, you can set
  # :secure => true in order to force SSL only cookies.
  # config.rememberable_options = {}

  # ==> Configuration for :validatable
  # Range for password length. Default is 8..128.
  config.password_length = 8..128

  # Email regex used to validate email formats. It simply asserts that
  # an one (and only one) @ exists in the given string. This is mainly
  # to give user feedback and not to assert the e-mail validity.
  # config.email_regexp = /\A[^@]+@[^@]+\z/

  # ==> Configuration for :timeoutable
  # The time you want to timeout the user session without activity. After this
  # time the user will be asked for credentials again. Default is 30 minutes.
  # config.timeout_in = 30.minutes

  # If true, expires auth token on session timeout.
  # config.expire_auth_token_on_timeout = false

  # ==> Configuration for :lockable
  # Defines which strategy will be used to lock an account.
  # :failed_attempts = Locks an account after a number of failed attempts to sign in.
  # :none            = No lock strategy. You should handle locking by yourself.
  # config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts

  # Defines which key will be used when locking and unlocking an account
  # config.unlock_keys = [ :email ]

  # Defines which strategy will be used to unlock an account.
  # :email = Sends an unlock link to the user email
  # :time  = Re-enables login after a certain amount of time (see :unlock_in below)
  # :both  = Enables both strategies
  # :none  = No unlock strategy. You should handle unlocking by yourself.
  # config.unlock_strategy = :both

  # Number of authentication tries before locking an account if lock_strategy
  # is failed attempts.
  # config.maximum_attempts = 20

  # Time interval to unlock the account if :time is enabled as unlock_strategy.
  # config.unlock_in = 1.hour

  # ==> Configuration for :recoverable
  #
  # Defines which key will be used when recovering the password for an account
  # config.reset_password_keys = [ :email ]

  # Time interval you can reset your password with a reset password key.
  # Don't put a too small interval or your users won't have the time to
  # change their passwords.
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours

  # ==> Configuration for :encryptable
  # Allow you to use another encryption algorithm besides bcrypt (default). You can use
  # :sha1, :sha512 or encryptors from others authentication tools as :clearance_sha1,
  # :authlogic_sha512 (then you should set stretches above to 20 for default behavior)
  # and :restful_authentication_sha1 (then you should set stretches to 10, and copy
  # REST_AUTH_SITE_KEY to pepper)
  # config.encryptor = :sha512

  # ==> Configuration for :token_authenticatable
  # Defines name of the authentication token params key
  # config.token_authentication_key = :auth_token

  # ==> Scopes configuration
  # Turn scoped views on. Before rendering "sessions/new", it will first check for
  # "users/sessions/new". It's turned off by default because it's slower if you
  # are using only default views.
  # config.scoped_views = false

  # Configure the default scope given to Warden. By default it's the first
  # devise role declared in your routes (usually :user).
  # config.default_scope = :user

  # Set this configuration to false if you want /users/sign_out to sign out
  # only the current scope. By default, Devise signs out all scopes.
  # config.sign_out_all_scopes = true

  # ==> Navigation configuration
  # Lists the formats that should be treated as navigational. Formats like
  # :html, should redirect to the sign in page when the user does not have
  # access, but formats like :xml or :json, should return 401.
  #
  # If you have any extra navigational formats, like :iphone or :mobile, you
  # should add them to the navigational formats lists.
  #
  # The "*/*" below is required to match Internet Explorer requests.
  # config.navigational_formats = ["*/*", :html]

  # The default HTTP method used to sign out a resource. Default is :delete.
  config.sign_out_via = :delete

  # ==> OmniAuth
  # Add a new OmniAuth provider. Check the wiki for more information on setting
  # up on your models and hooks.
  # config.omniauth :github, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET', :scope => 'user,public_repo'

  # ==> Warden configuration
  # If you want to use other strategies, that are not supported by Devise, or
  # change the failure app, you can configure them inside the config.warden block.
  #
  # config.warden do |manager|
  #   manager.intercept_401 = false
  #   manager.default_strategies(:scope => :user).unshift :some_external_strategy
  # end

  # ==> Mountable engine configurations
  # When using Devise inside an engine, let's call it `MyEngine`, and this engine
  # is mountable, there are some extra configurations to be taken into account.
  # The following options are available, assuming the engine is mounted as:
  #
  #     mount MyEngine, at: "/my_engine"
  #
  # The router that invoked `devise_for`, in the example above, would be:
  # config.router_name = :my_engine
  #
  # When using omniauth, Devise cannot automatically set Omniauth path,
  # so you need to do it manually. For the users scope, it would be:
  # config.omniauth_path_prefix = "/my_engine/users/auth"
end
```

Relevant code from development.rb

```
  # For mailer configs
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: "localhost:3000"}
```

What do I need to do to fix this issue? what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Exception is the result of strange usage of the value `Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options` in the view of this gem.

Looking into [mailer view code here](https://github.com/harrystech/prelaunchr/blob/master/app/views/user_mailer/signup_email.html.erb) we can see statements like this one:

```
CGI::escape(Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options || "")
```

so it seems that they expect, that this configuration option is a `String`, not a `Hash`. I confirmed this exception in my console:

```
> CGI::escape(Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options)
NoMethodError: undefined method `encoding' for {:host=>"localhost:3000"}:Hash
```

BTW: correct configuration should be `{ :host => "localhost", :port => "3000" }`, but it is not the root cause.

In my opinion the best way is to replace view part of this code with replaced host address with e.g. `url_for(:only_path => false)`.

Maybe it will work with setting up:

```
Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options = "http://localhost:3000/"
```

but this is not a correct way and may affect with a regression somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've made that change and went to restart my server and am no getting this error. /Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing': undefined method `“smtp' for #<Prelaunchr::Application:0x007fb20dd0da10> (NoMethodError)

Comment: @user3787971 Which change? Did you replaced url-s in that view or tried to modify `default_url_options`?

Comment: I changed the view as you suggested to url_for(Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options) and I changed the  { :host => "localhost", :port => "3000" }

Comment: @user3787971 I missed that it's Rails 3. I fixed my code replacing url method with `url_for(:only_path => false)`. I can't test it now but it should work.

Comment: Ok so I'm able to spin up the server now and I've changed the view again. My problem now is that it's only letting me enter in my email address and no other versions. I think this is because it's blocking my IP address(which it's supposed to do). Do I need to just change locations, clear the db? What would you suggest? After I'm able to submit a new user again then I think my mailer should work.

Comment: I'm not sure how is the reason but actually it may be "IP blocking". Removing the `ip_addresses` table contents should help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100705/discussion-between-user3787971-and-mareq).